# Why does `defined?` return a string or nil?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, why would `defined?` return a string? Most other ruby methods ending with a `?` return a boolean.

Was this a hack to support a feature request, or was there intentional misuse of ruby convention, and why?

Examples:

```
defined?(super)
=> "super"

defined?(nil)
=> "nil"

defined?(Object)
=> "constant"
```

Comment: 1. `defined?` is not a method. Hence, your description "all other ruby methods ... " is senseless. 2. It is not true that [all] methods with a `?` return a boolean. 3. What is the "ruby convention" that you have in mind? Until you clarify that, your question is not clear.

Comment: The `?` and `!` suffix conventions are very loose and Ruby isn't exactly known for its orthogonality. One could argue that the trailing `?` is sensible because strings are truthy and it returns a falsey `nil` at the right times. Or you could be honest and say that Ruby isn't terribly consistent (and probably make the fanboys through hissy fits).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it was neither a hack nor a misuse of Ruby convention. As matz writes in [ruby-talk 7986](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/7986):

> The '?' methods ... return either
>
> - (a) true or false
> - (b) non-false informative value or nil
>
> `defined?` falls into (b).

Also, as commenters have pointed out, `defined?` is not a method. Matz expands in [ruby-talk 1637](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/1637):

> [`defined?` is] a control structure.  Not everything is a message send in Ruby, e.g. control structures, variables, blocks are not objects. `defined?` is among these things.

Comment: Good answer for pointing out that Matz states that defined? falls into the method reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

As sawa points out [`defined?` is not actually a method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/26be081f1bfbe9bfa1ef45b14860c64bd409b12b/defs/keywords).

If it were, the Ruby source code docs states this is allowed for methods that end in a question mark.

> Methods that end with a question mark by convention return boolean. **But they may not always return just true or false**. Often they will may return an object to indicate a true value (or “truthy” value).

ref: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c8b3f1b470e343e7408ab5883f046b1056d94ccc/doc/syntax/methods.rdoc

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above, `defined?` is not a method. And it cannot be. If it were a method, an error would be raised when you check it against an undefined expression.

Comment: Good point. So the answer to the question is in fact `defined?` is not a method, therefore does not need to follow method convention.

Comment: I disagree, @Rots. It's reasonable to expect `defined?` to follow the '?' convention even though it is not a method. But the convention is not to return merely true or false.

Comment: I agree on your comment that it's reasonable to expect this @jonahb - it's intuitive that it returns a truthly value. Our answers are very similar with different references.